# Oracle APEX - hyperlink shown as text on a static region

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a static region and I want to set it to some text with a hyperlink. Text comes from the database - returned by a function.

So I added a page item (P1_LINK_TEXT) to the page and added a computation to my page item that is set to PL/SQL expression:

```
MyFunction('MY_TEXT')
```

The region `Header Text` to `&P1_LINK_TEXT.`

It works great, except the hyperlink displayed as is - `Click <a href="www.test.com">here</a>`
instead of displaying the link. I made sure that `Attributes->Settings->Output As` is set to `HTML` but still, the hyperlink is not displayed correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [escape filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html#GUID-CA3ABA44-D03D-4396-A527-B160F1FFE933) to ensure html characters are not escaped. To display the item as html use this notation:

```
&P1_LINK_TEXT!RAW.
```